# How to obtain all the distinct De Bruijn sequences?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

In combinatorial mathematics, a $k$-ary De Bruijn sequence $B(k, n)$ of order $n$ is a cyclic sequence of a given alphabet $A$ with size $k$ for which every possible subsequence of length $n$ in $A$ appears as a sequence of consecutive characters exactly once.

Each $B(k, n)$ has length $k^n$ and there are $\dfrac{(k!)^{k^{n-1}}}{k^n}$ distinct De Bruijn sequences.

By using `DeBruijnGraph` and `FindEulerianCycle` should be possible to obtain all the distinct sequences. In the example below I should obtain 24 sequences ($k = 3$, $n = 2$). However, I get only three distinct sequences:

```
out=FindEulerianCycle[DeBruijnGraph[3, 1], 24];
(First /@ #) & /@ out
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3}, {3, 1, 1, 
>     2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3}}

How can I obtain all the distinct De Bruijn sequences?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on MMA 9 -- I get 24 cycles.

Comment: I can reproduce the result in the question on version 8.0.4

Comment: So it is probably a bug of version 8 which I'm also running. It would be great to find a workaround though.

Comment: @mfvonh Just out of curiosity, does it work on MMA 9 if you run: `FindEulerianCycle[DeBruijnGraph[4, 1], 20736]`?

Comment: Have you tried using `FindHamiltonianCycle` (with appropriate adjustments to the graph, etc.) to see if perhaps the bug is in `FindEulerianCycle`? (I'm on 9, so both work...)

Comment: @rasher With `FindHamiltonianCycle[DeBruijnGraph[3, 1], 24]` I get the following warning: "The method currently implemented for `FindHamiltonianCycle` only accepts undirected graphs".

Comment: @VLC: Bummer, I had hopes there... (btw. the graph w/b 3,2 for using Hamiltonian paths, but looks like directed edges not implemented in 8, so matters not ...)

Comment: @VLC Yes the `20736` code works for me in MMA 9.

Answer (score 1):

An idea for a workaround, but the `Permutations` is pretty inefficient and quickly burns through memory. Any ideas how to improve this?

```
DeBruijnGraph[3, 1] // EdgeList
Cases[
  Permutations[List @@@ %],
  x_ /; x[[;; -2, 2]] == x[[2 ;;, 1]]];
NestWhile[
  RotateLeft, 
  #, 
  First@# != {1, 1} &] & /@ % // DeleteDuplicates;
Apply[DirectedEdge, %, {2}] // Length
```

> 24

Comment: This works for `DeBruijnGraph[3,1]`, but it get stuck for `DeBruijnGraph[4,1]`. There are too many possible permutations I guess. There must be another way that is less memory demanding.

Answer (score 1):

I post this (it was an approach to a [New York Times NumberPlay](http://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/pushing-buttons/)). Note there are major scaling issues for this (Hamiltonian cycles). Apologies if this is unhelpful.

Some examples:

```
f[k_, n_] := (k!)^k^(n - 1)/k^n
fun[alpha_, n_] := Module[{t, g, gp},
  t = Tuples[alpha, n];
  g = Map[Function[x, {#, Take[Join[#, {x}], -n]}], alpha] & /@ t;
  gp = DirectedEdge @@@ Join @@ Map[StringJoin, g, {3}]]
seq[u_] := Module[{tk},
  tk = u[[All, 1]];
  StringJoin @@ {First@tk}~Join~(StringTake[#, -1] & /@ Rest@tk)]
```

Some tests:
For 3 letter alphabet, 2 symbols: `f[3,2]` =24

```
grp = Graph[fun[{"a", "b", "c"}, 2], 
];
ham = FindHamiltonianCycle[grp, All];
Column[seq /@ ham]
```

yields the desired 24:

[image]

Similarly `f[4,2]` is 20736 :

```
Length@FindHamiltonianCycle[Graph[fun[CharacterRange["a", "d"], 2]], 
  All]
```

also yields 20736.

And just for illustration `f[4,1]` =6 (as f[n,1]=(n-1)!).

```
Column[seq /@ 
  FindHamiltonianCycle[Graph[fun[CharacterRange["a", "d"], 1]], All]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but `FindHamiltonianCycle` on MMA 8 accepts only undirected graphs, so, unfortunately, this approach doesn't work for me.

Comment: @VLC ok...did not appreciate that